# Why does "class new {" give a compilation error "identifier is expected"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, identifier

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class new 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Sytem.in);    
        System.out.println("enter a number...");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the number is " + a);
    }
    
}
```

it throws an indentifier error in line 3. States that an identifier is expected at line 3

```
new.java:3: error:   <identifier> expected
```

Comment: You can't name you class `new`, it's a java keyword.

Comment: as @Progman describe new is a java keyword. In addition, i suggestion for you is to use capital letters for a class naming

Answer (score 6):

The word `new` belongs to the [Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) and thus cannot be used as identifier.